# using an iterator to search for a specific value in a HashMap

Tags: java, bluej

I am trying to search for a specific value in a HashMap, using an iterator, currently I have this method. I am very new to Java so your help would be greatly appreciated. helper.readAMap is hashmap which stores responses, which are generated when a user types in a certain word.

```
   public String generateResponse(String words)
{
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap();
    map = helper.readAMap("replies.txt");
    Iterator<String> it = map.keySet();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        String word = it.next();
        String response = map.get(word);
        if(response != null) {
            return response;
        }
    } 
    return pickDefaultResponse();

}
```

Comment: What, exactly, is your problem? What output are you getting and what output do you expect?

Comment: A key, of type String, will never, ever, be equal to a HashSet<String>. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Thomas, basically I am trying to search the replies.txt file for the words a user types. It should search through the file and return the correct response based on the word the user types.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
if(key.equals(words)) {
```

You compare a `String` to a `HashSet` of `Strings`. **That is like comparing an apple to a pear; it will always be false.**

So you either want a single `String` as argument to your method, or you want to generate responses to all of the words.

I expect you want to do this:

```
if(words.contains(key)) { // Your input contains the key
    return map.get(key); // Retrieve the response to the key from the map
}
```

Comment: basically I am trying to search the replies.txt file for the words a user types. It should search through the file and return the correct response based on the word the user types.